# How do I comment on people's question?

Tags: discussion, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

No, I don't ask about how to answer a question, but make a comment on people's question or answer. I didn't see any comment button.

Comment: well, this is weird. Because, now I see the 'add comment' button :(

Comment: You're always able to comment on and edit your *own* questions, regardless of reputation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I updated the /faq to clarify this point.

> you can always comment on your questions and answers, and any answers to questions you've asked, even with 1 rep.

Comment: OK. So how do I add a comment, or question about a comment, if I'm not reputable enough yet. IOW, I want to ask a question about the third answer (the animated graphic) of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803/what-is-the-most-elegant-proof-of-the-pythagorean-theorem.

Comment: @jeff see answer at http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51939

Answer (score 4):

You need 50 rep to post on other people's questions and answers on other people's questions. You can comment on answers to your own questions.

Comment: not quite, you can comment on any post you own, and any answer to a question you've asked.

Answer (score 2):

You need at least 50 rep to comment

edit: or at least at one time you did...

Answer (score 2):

It's 50 rep to comment on SO, 1 to comment at MSO. We have low standards here. We even let TheTXI be a moderator, so it shows you how seriously we take this place.

Comment: We haven't lowered yet enough to make you a mod, though.

Comment: @TXI: Lord help us all when we stoop to that level.

Comment: haha, nothing personal. I don't who is the moderator, as long he is fair enough with the power he got.

Comment: There aren't enough waffles in the world.

Comment: damn it, typo T_T. What Imean is "...I don't care who is..."

Comment: @silent: No worries, just ignore us. @TXI: You get paid in waffles?! DAMMIT, you could never afford me!