# Are new users allowed to comment/reply on questions?

Tags: support, comments, new-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the comment system and comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-the-comment-system-and-comments-work)

My question:

On SO, are new users allowed to comment on a question?  I'd like to ask someone for clarification, without posting an actual answer (yet).  I can find no link or button marked "Comment" or "Reply" or bearing an obvious icon for replying.

Is commenting disallowed for new users?  If so, why isn't that written anywhere?

(Yes, I have read those FAQs that I could find, and searched in meta to no avail.)

Comment: All right, never mind -- after asking the question I found this post, which confirms that a reputation of 50 is needed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51926/new-users-cant-ask-for-clarifications-except-as-answers

Comment: The ability to comment after 50 rep is also mentioned in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) under the "What is Reputation?" section.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the comment system and comments work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-the-comment-system-and-comments-work) -- please see the top answer.

Comment: Ah, my mistake.  I had searched the FAQ, and meta, for the word "reply" instead of "comment".  For someone who can't yet comment, there is no indication, on-screen, that these are called "comments".

Comment: Good point, thanks! I edited the question to add the `[comment-replies]` tag, since that is partially covered in there.

Comment: You can always comment on your own questions and answers though, regardless of reputation