# Why are all the "+1 for foo..." replies out there?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are all the “+1” comments really necessary?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15290/are-all-the-1-comments-really-necessary)

I see a lot of these and I think it's just noise... If you voted up, why does everyone need to know that you did it? Why brag about it? Especially since a lot of these are just to say "+1 for for this catchy phrase that you used somewhere in your answer and I find it really, really cool, so I am cool too, yaaay".

So if you just want to get to some helpful information, you have to filter through all these unnecessary replies. Considering that on several occasions I've had people remove my "Thank you" at the end of my question because that is considered "noise", I don't see why these types of comments should be out there and "tolerated".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this is not tolerated. These comments are almost universally agreed to be noise.

Whenever you see comments like this, flag them for moderator attention and they will be removed. The "too chatty" option is a good choice for a flag reason.

[image]

There *might* be [a few edge cases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85733/what-makes-a-good-valid-1-comment) where comments including the phrase `+1` *are* usefully contributing something to the discussion. But between your judgment and the judgment of the moderator who processes the flag, I trust that these will be left behind while the noise is removed.

Related: [Are all the "+1" comments really necessary?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15290/are-all-the-1-comments-really-necessary)

[Jeff agreed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15290/are-all-the-1-comments-really-necessary/15292#15292) a long time ago that these are unnecessary, although he advised flagging as "noise", which is no longer offered as a flag reason.

Answer (score 20):

If you see a comment that's just noise then flag it for moderator attention.

There is a fine line here. The comment:

> +1 for mentioning *this particular aspect*

*may* be useful - it draws attention to the particular part of the answer that's the most relevant.

However, I agree that most of these are probably just noise (and I've probably been guilty of adding some myself).

Comment: `+1` for showing the redeeming qualities of these comments.  For that reason alone, I think it's best to just leave the comments be.

Comment: Consider the present case: I agree with you that emphasizing a *specific portion* of an answer is useful and valuable, but I don't agree that "most" of these are noise (most "+1" comments I've seen had some sort of explanation to make them useful). So I leave this comment to clarify the upvote I've just given you, and emphasize the value of that specific point. What better example could there be?

Comment: I don't get it. Is jjnguy's comment supposed to be a joke? Because it doesn't add anything to the answer that isn't immediately apparent upon reading it. 2/3 of what Chris has posted covers the redeeming qualities of these comments specifically. Why do you need to tell us that that's why you `+1`ed his answer? Just +1 it and be quiet about it.

Answer (score 3):

You can always flag them as "not constructive" or "too chatty" and let a moderator decide whether they are noise.  Occasionally, I think it is constructive for someone to record their rationale for an upvote, but by and large this has the potential to be abused.