# Is it OK to say +1 with a reason why you're upvoting?

Tags: discussion, comments

When you go to post a comment on an answer, it says this:

> Use comments to ask for more information or clarification. Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks".

Would it be acceptable to say +1 with a reason why you're upvoting? For example:

> +1 for using an easier-to-use method than the accepted answer.

Comment: Of course, why not? The only time I'd imagine it'd be discourage-worthy is when it's superfluous, like *+1 this is a good answer!*. Try to make it as substantive as you can.

Comment: It's no different from people saying *"I'm downvoting this because..."*, and that is encouraged. Explaining why an answer is good is a positive thing.

Comment: relevant, perhaps even dupe? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85733/what-makes-a-good-valid-1-comment?lq=1  (Not hammering, just suggesting.)

Comment: it is acceptable to say +1 as soon as your comment is [longer than 120 chars](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283953/839601): "dropping this restriction for comments that exceed 120 characters in length..."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's OK, but usually is unnecessary. Indeed, for the case you describe, it would probably be better to comment on the accepted answer to say why the other one is better.

Answer (score 13):

Ideally, if you have a bit of information that further supports or improves an answer, **you should add it to the *body* of the post**. More often than not, folk who simply want to chime in with interesting anecdotes or comments like *"+1 That happened to me, too!"* add a degree of noise that simply is *not* what comments were designed for.

Comments are there to ask for clarification or to help improve the post. Supporting information should be contained in the post itself.

If a comment isn't directed at changing the post or causing some other action to be taken, they start to take on the role of miniature chat rooms, and that type of ongoing discussion folks have to dig through to get to the "finished" answer is exactly the type of activity Stack Exchange was designed to avoid.

Comment: I know that answers aren't "owned" by people per se... but I have authorship issues with adding content to someone's answer... I mean, one of the edit decline reasons is that the edit significantly alters the answer... Now, I get that this is generally in relation to someone editing an answer to flip what it says (like from "no" to "yes")... but ... It still seems inappropriate to me. Is there a guide on editing answers somewhere and where to draw the line? I generally only make textual/grammatical changes.

Comment: @Catija it's easy enough for them to rollback the edit. You get a notification for when your post is edited anyways.

Comment: @Catija This is an "issue" I wish we could overcome. Wiki editing of the post is at the very ***core*** of how Stack Exchange is supposed to work. The problem is that the comment UI is conspicuously close to the post, so as much as we say "comments are second-class citizens", there really isn't anything in the UI that says comments are transient by nature... and anything you say in comments really *isn't* as good as being in the post itself. I hope to fix that problem if anyone will listen.

Answer (score 6):

It would only be OK if the comment would still be a constructive non-chatty comment without the +1. However... at that point, why include the +1? It doesn't really add anything to the comment.

I would consider your example ok, but it would be even better if posted on the accepted answer (with slightly changed wording)