# I can't post a "+1 this is awesome" comment on an awesome post

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, voting

**This is not a duplicate of [What makes a good/valid +1 comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85733/what-makes-a-good-valid-1-comment) because I don't want feedback about *when* to post a +1 comment; it's about *the system not letting me post a +1 comment.***

## [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign): Upvotes are not a reason to comment, it seems... only if this ever got deleted, since I can't vandalize (so the content is below).

Look at this thumbnail for example:

[image: THAT is unfair!]

I really don't believe my comment was `+1, I upvoted yeah!`. It says the *reason* I've up-voted the post, but, that reason contains the word  `upvoted`. It's this post:

[Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/11227902#11227902)

If I'm not clear, here is the summary: I *have* specified a reason for my up-vote, and that should go to the comments, since there is no "upvote with a reason" option ***yet*** (wish I had it). Instead, when I downvote, the voting system encourages me to comment:

> **Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved.**

If this is not a reason, I will delete the question, but, if it is, please improve the comment system.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I really believe I have provided a reason :(

Comment: Maybe, but it's not a bug. You could try starting a discussion about it, not throw a bug report in the face of the team. That's not really constructive. (This works as intended, so it can't possibly be a bug)

Comment: Let my try to understand this - your complaint is that you're not able to leave a comment that says `+1 because this is the most upvoted post I've ever seen!`? Why do you want to leave that comment? What makes you think anyone reading that post want's to see that comment?

Comment: @JonW If you only clicked on that link...

Comment: I did click the link. It took me to an answer that has a lot of upvotes. I can see it has lots of upvotes because of the number against the post itself. What possible benefit is there to me to read a comment underneath that answer that points out someone (i.e. you) upvoted it because it has lots of upvotes?

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος such comments are just noise. A mess that moderators have to clean.

Comment: @JonW Well, it has 20K upvotes. 20. K! It really needed the effort for it so be the world-record most-upvoted Stack Overflow and most-upvoted Stack Exchange post *ever*. It deserves an upvote.

Comment: SO WHAT IF IT HAS 20K UPVOTES? Why should that mean it's OK to leave pointless +1 comments? A comment is supposed to be used to request clarification or to point out issues with a post.

Comment: You're basically asking "I should be able to post useless comments on questions / answers that have lots of upvotes".

Comment: Comments are not there for noise. Discussion boards are.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment: Please read the 'When should I comment' and 'When shouldn't I comment' sections.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος so send flowers to the author of that answer, that would help him/her more than yet another "+1 it's so amazing" comment. (which I'm sure there were hundreds of those, cleaned by moderators.)

Comment: As others have said - the whole "+1" comment pattern is an anti-pattern. It isn't helpful. So we try to disallow it. Which works often enough that it is worth keeping.

Comment: @Oded how do you know "it's working often enough"? Each blocked attempt is documented?

Comment: @Oded I didn't say `+1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1`, I provided a reason. If the reason is not a valid one, please vote to delete the question (i.e. the question is stupid, but I can't vote to delete it). I've only seen it on SO. Codegolf.SE and Puzzling.SE don't have anything like that, for example.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - we have a count of how often a block was hit.

Comment: @Sha not sure if you have seen this, but Shog shared [some statistics on SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283953/993547).

Comment: @PatrickHofman Your comment is true, and the statistics have... terrible results :(

Answer (score 14):

You can't, and shouldn't, add `+1`. That's it. That you have upvoted is not important at all. It encourages thanks-for-upvoting-me-upvotes and adds nothing to the Q/A set.

Your comment isn't useful at all since just telling you upvoted because everyone else did is not a good reason. Better explain why the post was as helpful as it was to you. *That* would be constructive and useful for future readers.

Comment: +1 (SUCCESS, not real upvote) Actually, it's a SE upvote record, not just "everyone else". Also, I've had success with `+1`s in the past, that's why I'm asking. I have had problems in the past, but I have done some comments with `+1` in them. Maybe it's the position of the `+1` that is disturbing, but, again, no. It seems to be some sort of weird combination, and your suggestion is part of it.

Comment: That you can circumvent the system is clear and well-known. Still, you shouldn't do that.

Comment: So the system is broken/useless.

Comment: No, it works in 95% of the cases, which is good.

Comment: Wait? Do I... FALL IN THE 5% TOO OFTEN? I'm amazed of my luck now. It seems 95% is not enough, you need 100%. There are *too much* +1-style comments out there, in case you didn't know.

Comment: You can't since 1+1 is a valid comment. You can't really prevent it without too much false positives. That is why it is not too hard to circumvent it, but it really does help as proven [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283953/993547).

Comment: ...... so.. much... bad....... percentages.... I CANT TAKE IT, HELP!!! [Serious mode] Also, this has to be on Meta SE, not MSO. Also, read [here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283874/283953#comment145781_283953).

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have had success on MSO, also.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος OK, so it's not active on meta sites.