# Comments: You've heard of +1, you've heard of -1. Now get ready for ±0!

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

In comments, **some people voluntarily** write "+1" or "-1" to indicate what they did vote-wise on the post. But when people want to say that they weren't the person who downvoted, there's no way to really say that concisely. So I propose "±0", which would function the exact same way but mean that the commenter did not vote on the post.

I see this inconvenience usually when a post has a negative score and someone has some normal comment but doesn't want to be mistakenly identified as the downvoter.

As an example of what I think is a nice easy way to convey this,

> (I didn't downvote btw) Could you please clarify the problem you're having?

could become

> Could you please clarify the problem you're having? ±0

I think it's a lot simpler. I know, it's Unicode, and not everyone can get with that. I guess "+/-0" would be the normal text option.

**Does anyone have any input on why this would or would not be a good idea?**

Note: I'm not proposing that people be required to do this for their votes. I know you guys hate "make votes require a comment" posts, but don't worry, this is just about how commenters can indicate this voluntarily, like they already do for their upvotes (and sometimes downvotes).

Comment: We already actively block comments containing the text "-1", and moderators already zealously delete "+1" and "-1" comments in response to flags. So...I think it's pretty established that this is not a good idea. Your idea is even worse, as a "+0" comment would literally convey *no* information. That's the worst kind of comment.

Comment: @CodyGray Really? Moderators actively remove comments containing "+1" or "-1"? Is that sitewide policy or does that vary by site? Also, it would convey information, as it lets people know what you *didn't do* so they don't assume it.

Comment: I usually see these in response to "why the downvote" comments.  Someone else will provide a guess (or two) as to why the post was downvoted, and usually include ways it can be improved to remove those reasons.  The "I didn't downvote" clarifies that it is a guess.  The +/-0 would just add to the confusion.

Comment: @user45266 Not only that, the software itself actively blocks instances of -1 it can recognize.

Comment: Related on MSO: [Should we discourage leading +/-1 on comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277314) and [Remove the limitation that stops comments from starting with +1 or -1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283953)

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya I'm pretty sure everyone read what the OP wrote. Unless comments are deleted the current visible ones seem to explain short comings of what the question is about. And some of those comments seems valuable, even for the OP. To me those comments server their design goal and they all seem to convey factual information that is not present in the question itself. Stil, if you feel some of those comments cross a line, do flag them for a moderator. Moderators are ruthless towards anything that is not nice.

Comment: I've dug through [these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85733/what-makes-a-good-valid-1-comment/) [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339009/making-valid-use-of-comments-containing-1) meta questions which now invalidates all the answers, and I recommend you to look at those.

Comment: @user45266 - After you read the two posts, I'll have to suggest you to mention them in your post so it can be clarified.

Comment: @Maika_Sakuran0miya I think the intent of this post has already been achieved quite clearly; the community has spoken pretty much unanimously. Thank you for the links, but I'll not be needing them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Votes are meant to be anonymous, as would be the lack of votes.

In addition, we're adding an informal, not very clear shorthand a new user to SE would not get, for a problem a new user might face. In short, your target audience would not understand what ±0 means. *Asking for clarification without mentioning votes is entirely fine, and works just as well*.