# How do I gain the ability to comment on questions and answers?

Tags: support, reputation, comments

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

I want to be able to comment on questions and answers, but I don't appear to have permission. I think I need a certain badge, but cannot find out what I need to do to get these permissions. Is there a page that explains this?

Comment: See also: [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12119/162705) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51926/162705).

Answer (score 3):

The [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) (linked at the top of every page) has a section on reputation that tells you what you need to know.  You need 50 reputation to leave comments, except for on your own questions and answers, where you can always comment.