# Prompting for further information

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New users can't ask for clarifications except as answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51926/new-users-cant-ask-for-clarifications-except-as-answers)

Today is my first day using stackoverflow and as such I cannot yet comment - as you need 50 rep points to do so.  As such adding answers is my only way to communicate, that I know of.

How would you suggest I interact with the question-asker and prompt for further information without being lambasted by those that have said 50 rep?

(This questions has no newbie or faq or question tag; new is the most appropriate tag I could find - I'd need 1500 rep create a new tag)

Answer (score 2):

Attempt to answer the question making educated guesses on the information that is missing.

**You must state all of the things that you are assuming** and when/if the OP decides to give some more info, you can always update your post.

- **For example** - if the OP is asking about a certain jQuery function but "forgot" to include a sample of the HTML markup they are using, invent your own markup and give your answer based on that.
- **Another example** - if the OP "forgot" to specify what language they are using (but you can safely assume that he is using web technologies), give an answer in JavaScript.