# I can see ghosts (aka empty "add comment" link)

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, hyperlinks

While researching a reported bug on https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/ with a sock account having 1 rep, I noticed I can't see "add comment" meaning [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144537/152859) is no longer [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

However, in my attempts to find the "add comment" I did notice this:

> [image]

Yep, that's an empty `<a>` element having a title but no contents.

[Short video if you like](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EG3DDIJhDp4).

Can this ghost link please be removed, or better yet be replaced with "to comment you have to [etc etc]"?

Comment: Cool, thank you; must have been a glitch my side. It seemed to break the new top-bar when there was a pending refresh but science says no...

Comment: @ben live updates in the new top bar were added only yesterday and probably still not 100% stable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from the next build (rev 2013.11.25.1175), the `add comment` link will come up for anonymous and users without comment everywhere privileges as well.

For users without the privileges, an error telling them what amount of rep is required will come up.

Anonymous users will get a similar popup to the one they get when upvoting/downvote/favoriting a post.

Comment: Wow still 2013.11.22.1174 any ETA when next build is coming? Hope not 6-8 weeks.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Not sure. There are a few um... scary... changes in the pipeline there and I think people would be more comfortable pushing once they are actually "at work". So, probably sometime early Monday.

Comment: Isn't it a record, over 48 hours without a single build? By the way. to see your reply now I had to use the old inbox (on the main site) the inbox here on Meta stopped working. (Going to escalate my report) (edit: never mind regarding inbox, just caching)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Probably not a record, not when you consider weekends (and dev summits...)