# Why not hide the "add comment" option?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, comments

If a there's a new user with less than 50 reputation Stack Overflow must hide the "add comment" option instead of displaying a popup saying: "You need 50 reputation to comment". And then if the user reaches 50 reputation it must show a notification saying something like: "You have been enabled to comment".

So the "add comment" option will only show if the user has 50 reputation.

Comment: This allows for the differentiation of comments from answers. At present a large number of new users **still** post comments as answers. If they didn't know comments even existed this would be even more prevalent

Comment: The logic behind showing it to all is at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144537/show-the-add-comment-link-also-to-users-who-cannot-add-comments among other places

Comment: Closing as a dupe of [Show the "add comment" link also to users who cannot add comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144537) because the *inverse* was implemented on purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New users will still see comments on other posts and wonder why they can't post them if you simply hide the comment link. It's better to leave the user interface element there and let them click it, showing them a clear message of why they can't use it yet, rather than hiding it altogether and confusing the heck out of them.

See also: [Don't hide or disable menu items](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/07/01.html)